# navigator with vaadin null pointer exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I'm new to vaadin and I'm building an app requiring the use of multiple views,
here are the code snippets and the stack trace,
i've checked the build path to be sure that it's not a dependecy problem and google searches gave no useful answers or leads

```
Button button = new Button("Login", new Button.ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event){
            layout.addComponent(new Label("establishing connection ..."));
            getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("");
            }

        });
@Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and this is the navigator class :

```
public class navigator extends LoInf {
    Navigator navigator;
    public static final String MAINVIEW = "main";
    //public static final String view = "interface";

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        getPage().setTitle("login");


        navigator = new Navigator(this,this);


        navigator.addView(MAINVIEW, new LoInf());
        navigator.addView("", RMQcl.class);
    }

    public static void navigateTo(String mainview2) {


    }

}
```

and here's the stack trace

```
oct. 24, 2017 3:05:30 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
GRAVE: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.vaadin.Project.LoInf$1.buttonClick(LoInf.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:211)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:174)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1033)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:370)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1568)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:381)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

can't seem to figure out what the issue is,
Help appreciated

[update]
this is the class i'm trying to navigate to:

```
@SpringUI
public class RMQcl extends RMQ implements UserRep,View{
    UserRep repo;
    Grid <UserModel> grid;
    TextField filter = new TextField();
    UserEdit editor;
    Button addnew;  
    UserModel User;
    Binder<UserModel> binder = new Binder<>(UserModel.class);
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(filter,grid);
    @Autowired
    public RMQcl(UserRep repo,UserEdit editor){
        this.repo = repo;
        this.grid = new Grid<>(UserModel.class);
        this.editor = editor;
        this.filter = new TextField();
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        this.addnew = new Button("New User",FontAwesome.PLUS);

        logout = new Button("Logout");
        logout.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                     getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(navigator.MAINVIEW);


            }

    });


}
    //@Override
    public void init(VaadinRequest request){
        layout.addComponents(grid);
        setContent(layout);
        listUsers(null);
        binder.setBean(User);
        HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout(filter,addnew);
        VerticalLayout Layout = new VerticalLayout(actions,grid,editor);
        setContent(Layout);

        grid.setHeight(300,Unit.PIXELS);
        grid.setColumns("id","firsname","lastname");
        filter.setPlaceholder("Filtering by lastname");

        filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        filter.addValueChangeListener(e->listUsers(e.getValue()));


        grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(e->{
            editor.editUser(e.getValue());
        });
        addnew.addClickListener(e -> editor.editUser(new UserModel("", "")));

        editor.setChangeHandler(()->{
            editor.setVisible(false);
            listUsers(filter.getValue());
        });

        listUsers(null);

    }

    private void setContent(VerticalLayout layout2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    private void listUsers(String Filter) {
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(Filter)){
        grid.setItems(repo.findAll());
        }else{
            grid.setItems(repo.findByLastNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(Filter));
        }

        filter.setPlaceholder("Filter by last name");
        filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        filter.addValueChangeListener(e-> listUsers(e.getValue()));
        setContent(layout);


    }
```

Comment: What's at `LoInf.java:43`?

Comment: How do you initialize `layout` before your `buttonClick()` method?

Comment: @Morfic it's the line 'getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("");' from the main UI

Comment: @pirho it's vertical layout  'final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();'

Comment: Hmmm, from the stacktrace it originates in `LoInf`and you say it happens in the click listener which seems to be defined in a view class, so something is missing. Can you please post all of the relevant code so we can understand the full flow? Or better yet, a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce it easily.

Comment: @Morfic i do have a slight doubt that it could be when i try to call the UI, i'm hesitating between calling the parameterized constructor or a new instance however here's the relevant code

Comment: Please edit your post to add the relevant code when it's this big. Nonetheless, do `LoInf` & `RMQcl` both extent UI? Asking 'cause I see a `@SpringUI` on `RMQcl`. You probably want to have only one UI and 2 separate views, something like `AppUI` with the `init` method where you configure the navigator and add the 2 views, `LoInf` & `RMQcl`.

Comment: yes i edited the main question, and will look into using a single UI, thanks for the assistance

Comment: @Morfic I changed the code to get rid of the null pointer exception by removing the navigator class and integrating it's components to my initial view, however now i have a class not found exception telling me that the the view cannot be found, the problem is what i'm trying to access is a class and i'm calling the constructor which is parameterized with a repository interface and another class and i couldn't figure out how to pass the parameters when calling it, i have tried calling the entire class but that didn't work, can you shed some light on this ?

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code and stacktrace I can't really say based on just this description. Try opening a new question and add there all the details.